# Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found - also Windows7 dual boot failure after second install!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 64-bit

Installation is on an MSI-7680 MB, with i7-2660 processor, 8G, and 1 TB disk.

Procedure followed is per instructions on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows using the Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.8.exe.

I can install the 32-bit version with no trouble (ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso), but that is "only" 32-bit.

Using the same procedure with the 64-bit .iso (ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso) I can boot from the USB - in 64-bit mode,
but after install (either after booting to USB Desktop, or without booting to desktop). I have reinstalled the USB (with a server
version - with 'desktop' added to name so the Universal installer would see it - but choose to not install because I did not trust
the disk partition feedback (rewrite all changes before I had made any changes??).

Also tried installing both with/without download updates during install.

Moreover, tried "something else" option, as well as "overwrite Ubuntu" install option.

In all cases - i386 installs and boots, amd64 installs but does not boot.

"Blue screen" panic messages:

```
...
Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found
CPU:4 PID:1 swapper/0 not tainted 3.13.0-32-generic #57-ubuntu
Hardware Name MSI MS-7680/HB7MA-E35 BIOS V11.12 01/11/2012
00000000 00000000 f74b3f78 c1650cd3 3ae1d146 f74b3f98 c164be0c c12bd0b4
c1aabc80 c181b7b0 3a21d146 00000000 c1942e40 f7b43fac c164714c c181bc98
ca8ab7a0 fffffff8 f7b42000 c165ef37 c1647050 00000000 00000000 00000000
<c1650cd3> dump_stack+0x41/0x52
<c164be0c> panic+0x87/0x181
<c164714c> kernel_init+0xfc/0x100
<c165ef37> ret_from_kernel_thread+0x1b/0x28
<c1647050> ? rest_init+0x70/0x70
```

Note: perhaps the hex code was all caps and/or I typed one or more incorrectly. I hope I got them all right.

Considering that there are others, who with differing versions have had this, and 'fixed' it back going to older versions
(e.g., 4.12 LTS) I hope there might be an solution that can be achieved by installing per instructions, then booting to
'trial USB desktop' and then using that environment to edit/update GRUB on the installed image and/or run a verification
of what has been installed.

Thanks for your time and assistance.

Addition: after installing amd64 to additional partition - sda7 - sda6 (with i386) continues to boot.

```
michael@u037:~$ cd /media/michael/16*
michael@u037:/media/michael/16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0$ ls
bin   cdrom  etc   initrd.img  lib64       media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr  vmlinuz
boot  dev    home  lib         lost+found  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var
michael@u037:/media/michael/16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0$ ls -l sbin/init; file sbin/init
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 265848 jul 18 11:46 sbin/init
sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=7a4c688d009fc1f06ffc692f5f42ab09e68582b2, stripped
michael@u037:/media/michael/16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0$ ls -l /sbin/init; file /sbin/init
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 252080 jul 18 11:48 /sbin/init
/sbin/init: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=c394677bccc720a3bb4f4c42a48e008ff33e39b1, stripped
michael@u037:/media/michael/16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0$ 

michael@u037:/media/michael/16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0$ diff -u /boot/grub/grub.cfg boot/grub/grub.cfg
--- /boot/grub/grub.cfg 2015-01-10 14:36:41.251418853 +0100
+++ boot/grub/grub.cfg  2015-01-11 16:06:44.702291960 +0100
@@ -16,7 +16,7 @@
    save_env next_entry
    set boot_once=true
 else
-   set default="Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)"
+   set default="0"
 fi

 if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
@@ -66,9 +66,9 @@
 insmod ext2
 set root='hd0,msdos7'
 if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
-  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0
 else
-  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0
 fi
     font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
 fi
@@ -99,7 +99,7 @@
 ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
 set menu_color_normal=white/black
 set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
-if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
+if background_color 44,0,30; then
   clear
 fi
 ### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
@@ -131,7 +131,7 @@
   set linux_gfx_mode=text
 fi
 export linux_gfx_mode
-menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3' {
+menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
@@ -140,15 +140,15 @@
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
-     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0
    else
-     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0
    fi
-   linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
+   linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
 }
-submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3' {
-   menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-advanced-9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3' {
+submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0' {
+   menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-advanced-16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
@@ -157,16 +157,16 @@
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
-         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0
        else
-         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
-       linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
+       linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
-   menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-recovery-9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3' {
+   menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-recovery-16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
@@ -174,12 +174,12 @@
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
-         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0
        else
-         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
-       linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3 ro recovery nomodeset 
+       linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
@@ -197,9 +197,9 @@
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
-     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0
    else
-     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
 }
@@ -208,9 +208,9 @@
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
-     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0
    else
-     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
 }
@@ -229,6 +229,57 @@
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
 }
+menuentry 'Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/sda6)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3' {
+   insmod part_msdos
+   insmod ext2
+   set root='hd0,msdos6'
+   if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
+     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+   else
+     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+   fi
+   linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
+   initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
+}
+submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/sda6)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3' {
+   menuentry 'Ubuntu (on /dev/sda6)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic--9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3' {
+       insmod part_msdos
+       insmod ext2
+       set root='hd0,msdos6'
+       if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
+         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+       else
+         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+       fi
+       linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
+       initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
+   }
+   menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (on /dev/sda6)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic--9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3' {
+       insmod part_msdos
+       insmod ext2
+       set root='hd0,msdos6'
+       if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
+         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+       else
+         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+       fi
+       linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
+       initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
+   }
+   menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda6)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic-root=UUID=9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3 ro recovery nomodeset-9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3' {
+       insmod part_msdos
+       insmod ext2
+       set root='hd0,msdos6'
+       if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
+         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+       else
+         search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3
+       fi
+       linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3 ro recovery nomodeset
+       initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
+   }
+}
+
 set timeout_style=menu
 if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
   set timeout=10

michael@u037:/media/michael/16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 jan 11 16:16 16b5f3ef-7fa8-4fc6-b2c5-5437defd15d0 -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 jan 11 16:16 72A436C7A4368E1B -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 jan 11 16:16 8A4C0CA24C0C8AE1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 jan 11 16:16 9C701C16701BF5AC -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 jan 11 16:16 9de604d0-6721-4860-956e-7228905d8ba3 -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 jan 11 16:16 b47edfbf-0fec-4890-856f-938a68847ca7 -> ../../sda5
```

As far as I can tell, the result is equivalent, but it does not like 64-bit /sbin/init. I hope the diff -u gives enough comparision material (I had changed the GRUB to boot to w7 by default, as you can see)

EDIT2: cannot boot back to Windows!!! Here is RESULTS from bootinfscript: http://pastebin.com/57nYXeWS
=== 22 Jan 2015 == update
After getting Windows to boot again I have deleted UBUNTU. I will start fresh again (i.e., this has never been a update/upgrade - ALWAYS a fresh install) - but before I do, considering the potential to disrupt W7 - more advice (read encouragement!) is welcome.
I have nearly 35 years experience with UNIX, and was happy with Slackware in 1994-1996 timeframe. But I do not know the tools available to verify an installation.

My goal is to get someone else - who is not interested in understanding how to install/admin a system - to also install Linux besides Windows. I would not grade ubuntu as "fit for purpose" based on my experience this month. And I am sure that is not true (or I would not even ask a question!)

Again, thanks for your insight/answers.

Comment: Boot the USB, mount the partition where you installed Ubuntu, then check if `/sbin/init` exists (This can be done via Nautilus, I think). If it does, you should check your grub configuration to make sure the correct partition is being passed to the `root=` parameter. (Just open `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` with gedit, search for the parameter. if it's a UUID, check if it's the correct one with `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`). Please report back.

Comment: Rebuilding the USB. The situation will be a bit different as I do not want to discard everything from the i386 install atm. But there is enough space to install again (and compare!). Will report back shortly - thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Installed to new partition: sda6 is i386, sda7 is amd64/ since add a comment is so limited - more info follows in a regular reply.

Comment: @MichaelFelt hmm, could you show us the `...` in your panic message? Usually `init` has a reaseon to get panic (and kill itself). this reason would be interesting. common reasons are: less than 512 KiB ram; another process comitted suicid; init is damaged.

Comment: @mid_kid I do not think that his problem are the disks. Then he would stuck somewhere between `grub rescue` and `initramfs`. `init`comes a lot later (see the `bootstrap of a linux).

Comment: @LittleByBlue afaik, mounting is usually done by the initramfs. It is perfectly possible for grub to find the kernel/initramfs and load them, but the initramfs to fail mounting the disks and fail to run init.

Comment: @mid_kid but then `initramfs` would tell you this. Also `init` is not commiting suizid just because of an unmounted partition. it is much more likely, that his init is damaged, because of a failed upgrade or something like this.

Comment: @LittleByBlue - wish I could say what ... was, it is scrolled out of sight. i.e., ... is/are the lines I could not see. -- regarding bad /sbin/init - this is a fresh install, not an upgrade. There is 8G of RAM, the USB loads, rather boots, fine. The installer is not putting something there well. -- lastly, if I recall correctly (ircc) the pastbin I posted has lots of 'related' info. AND I was an unhappy camper when my W7 stopped booting. Ended up overwriting GRUB2 with Windows boot. Moving forward will mean I delete everything LINUX related and start again from scratch. Bother!

Comment: Back from away, many many problems behind me - such as update to Windows10. I still have the old system and disk - and shall see if I can recreate the problem using a "latest" version of Ubuntu. but not today!